# Word problem: Exterminator insecticide formula

Tags: algebra-precalculus

An exterminator needs to dilute a 25% solution of an insecticide with a 15% solution of the same insecticide. How many more liters of the 25% solution than the 15% solution are needed to make a total of 80 liters of a 22% solution of the insecticide?

Answer (score 0):

$x$ the number of liters at $25$%, $y$ the number of liters at $15$%, you have

$x+y=80$, ${{{25\over 100}x+{15\over 100}y}\over 80}*100={22\over 100}$ solve the system and calculate $x-y$.

Answer (score 0):

Using the same meaning of variable $x$ as Tsemo introduced, one can write down the equation: $25x+15(80-x)=22(80)$ and find $x$ form which the rest follows...